# Setting calculation mode to automatic in Excel workbook activate event disables inter-workbook copy-paste

Tags: vba, excel, excel-interop

I have a workbook with the following VBA code to ensure the formula calculation mode is set to automatic:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

If I open that workbook (let's call it WB1) and then any other workbook (WB2, opened under the same EXCEL.EXE instance), then I can't copy cells from WB2 to WB1. By "can't" I mean that when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> I hear Windows' "ding" sound and nothing happens.

If I use the following code instead, everything works fine.

```
' Now in Workbook_Open instead of Activate
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Is that behavior expected? Is this documented anywhere? Or is this a bug? Somehow I feel like I can't be the first person to do this.

I've tried with a C# Excel Add-In and using the equivalent Excel Interop code yields the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Ok so I figured this out as I was typing the question but I'll answer anyway if someone else ever wonders...</sub>

---

The issue is that calling `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` makes the original workbook lose focus (the moving lines around the cells to be copied disappear, as if I had pressed escape).

Since I put my code in `Workbook_Activate`, it was called every time I went to copy in WB1 and caused my issue.

Moving the code to `Workbook_Open` is a good enough solution for me, but I like to think that making Excel non-interactive while I'm changing the calculation mode would have worked. I did not test this solution tough.